# Replace the url without refreshing the page in .net

Tags: asp.net, iis

My default url home page is http://www.brindesbb.com/Pages/Default.aspx.
but I dont want to show `Pages/Default.aspx` in the address bar.

can anyone suggest me how to replace the url without reloading (refreshing ) the page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have full control of the IIS server? What version is it etc..

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is URL Rewriting, read more here [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

**Update:** If you setup a new website(or edit the one you have) and point the /Pages directory as "root" and aspx is an default document the url will be as you want.

Comment: <if  url="~/default.aspx">
      <rewrite url="~/(.+)" to="~/$1"  processing="stop"/>
    </if>

Comment: actually i need to show only http://www.brindesbb.com/ instead of http://www.brindesbb.com/Pages/Default.aspx. I don't think it is possible with URL Rewriting.

i need to show only the project name.
please have a check

Comment: please help me anyone.......... i am trying to keep only the domain name..... i dont think it is possible by url rewriting

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in two ways **IIS URL Rewriting** and **ASP.NET Routing**

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/

Comment: i have tried like this                                                <if  url="~/Pages/Default.aspx">
      <rewrite url="http://localhost:2249/Brindesbb/Pages/Default.aspx" to="http://localhost:2249/Brindesbb/"  processing="stop"/>
    </if>                                                           but its not working  . please help me

Comment: Take a look to this post and download the example you will know how to do it directly from the Global file. http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/

Answer (score 0):

Technically that not possible with .net as .net is used on server side. and you need to change the URL which is on client side so... you will need to use JavaScript to manipulate the Browser URL history. Example [asp.net mvc] my url is http://localhost:123/Home/Product 
 and I need to change it to 
  http://localhost:123/Home/Product/301 
 this can be achieved by

```
<script>
```

`window.history.pushState('', 'My Page', 'Home/Product/301');`

```
</script>
```